# Formatting of list array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a two dimensional list that looks like this

```
['Electronic Control Security Inc.', 'OTCPK:EKCS', 'EKCS']
['CardioComm Solutions, Inc.', 'OTCPK:EKGG.F', 'EKGG.F']
['EKO International Corp.', 'OTCPK:EKNL', 'EKNL']
['Eckoh plc', 'OTCPK:EKTP.F', 'EKTP.F']
['Ekwan X Inc.', 'OTCPK:EKWX', 'EKWX']
['El Al Israel Airlines Ltd.', 'OTCPK:ELAL.F', 'ELAL.F']
```

when I try to run the following block of code, i get an error saying

```
    symbol = row[0]. 
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

i cant figure out what is wrong. row is supposed to be a 1dimension list, and row [ 0 ] should give the first element in the list. no?

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path import exists
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account


class Scraper:

    def __init__(self) -> None:

        # google sheets service credential file
        self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'insiderownershipextract-17d37686d973.json'

        # # if not exists('InsiderOwnershipOutput.csv'):
        # with open('InsiderOwnershipOutput.csv', 'w') as out:
        #     out.write(f"{', '.join(self.data_headers)}\n")

    def read_scrape_list(self, input_spreadsheet_id, input_data_range) -> dict:

        in_file = {}
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

        credentials = None
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
        )

        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        result = sheet.values().get(
            spreadsheetId=input_spreadsheet_id,
            range=input_data_range
        ).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])
        # print(values)

        if not values:
            print('No data found.')
        else:
            for row in values:
                symbol = row[0]
                in_file[symbol] = row[2]

        return in_file
```

printing `values` looks like this

```
 [['Name', 'Full Ticker', 'Ticker'], [], [], ['CorMedix Inc.', 'NASDAQGM:CRMD', 'CRMD'], ['Intellicheck, Inc.', 'NASDAQGM:IDN', 'IDN'], ['IEC Electronics Corp.', 'NASDAQGM:IEC', 'IEC'], ['InspireMD, Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:NSPR', 'NSPR'], ['Oblong Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:OBLG', 'OBLG'], ['Atlantic American Corporation', 'NASDAQGM:AAME', 'AAME'], ['Applied Optoelectronics, Inc.', 'NASDAQGM:AAOI', 'AAOI'], ['Abeona Therapeutics Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:ABEO', 'ABEO'], ['ARCA biopharma, Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:ABIO', 'ABIO'], ['Arbutus Biopharma Corporation', 'NASDAQGS:AB
```

Comment: It looks `values` is non-empty, but at least one of the sub-lists is empty. What you show is not lists of lists, so we can't say more. Print `values` and post the output verbatim.

Comment: printing ``` values ``` looks like this

```

[['Name', 'Full Ticker', 'Ticker'], [], [], ['CorMedix Inc.', 'NASDAQGM:CRMD', 'CRMD'], ['Intellicheck, Inc.', 'NASDAQGM:IDN', 'IDN'], ['IEC Electronics Corp.', 'NASDAQGM:IEC', 'IEC'], ['InspireMD, Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:NSPR', 'NSPR'], ['Oblong Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:OBLG', 'OBLG'], ['Atlantic American Corporation', 'NASDAQGM:AAME', 'AAME'], ['Applied Optoelectronics, Inc.', 'NASDAQGM:AAOI', 'AAOI'], ['Abeona Therapeutics Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:ABEO', 'ABEO'], ['ARCA biopharma, Inc.', 'NASDAQCM:ABIO', 'ABIO'], ['Arbutus Biopharma Corporation', 'NASDAQGS:AB
```

Comment: As you can see you have 2 empty lists at index 1 and 2

Comment: You will have to add a check for that in your `for row in values` loop, either with a conditional (`if len(row) != 0`) or a `try: symbo = row[0]   except IndexError: ...`